# What's wrong with my current calculation for an LED panel?

Tags: led, electronics

I am trying to understand how much current is required for one LED matrix panel, however, I don't quite understand it in general.

Take [this panel](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2278) as an example. This is an 64x32 LED matrix, and its tech spec says **`5V regulated power input, ~4A max (all LEDs on)`**. I learned [one LED bulb consumes about 0.016A (assuming SMD3528)](http://www.ledlightsworld.com/page.html?id=38). Based on this knowledge, I thought it would required about **`0.016 x 64 x 32 = 32.768A`**, however, the spec says **`4A max`**, which is nowhere close to my calculation. Could you tell what I am missing here? Thank you!

Comment: The LED's may not actually all be on at the same time.  Humans can see about 50-60 Hz flicker. so turn on 3 rows for 1ms, then the next 3, ect, with 32 rows, this means every 10 ms the LED is on. Which is 100 Hz, wouldn't be noticeable to the human eye.  Not saying this is how THIS panel works, I didnt even look at it. But that is one way that it can look like they are all on, all the time, but you are not consuming the current of them all being on.

Comment: You could use the inputs on the pi(with voltage divider), or an arduino, or an actual o-scope to check the duty cycle of the LED's, even in their "ON" state, they may be getting a PWM signal turning them ON/OFF every few micro seconds, which will further decrease their overall current consumption.

Comment: @ChadG Thanks for your input. So basically my crude calculation is correct, but you mean this panel is somehow managing to limit the usage under 4A, right? In other words, if I make my custom led panel just by linking bulbs, it will consume about 32A. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: depends how its wired, if you give each LED 16mA then yes, your right, but LED's have very little resistance, the current through them is regulated by a resistor. So if you put 2 LED's in series, and allow 16mA to flow through them, they will both still light.  So it also depends on how its wired.

Comment: @ChadG okay, that makes sense. Thanks for giving me a great guideline!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Electronics SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec mentions PWM and a 16:1 scan rate, so each LED would only be on for 1/16 of the time.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Sorry, I don’t know PWM, but it sounds like each LED bulb would consume 1/16 of energy as it would be on 1/16 of the time that is asked to be on. Is that what ‘16:1 scan rate’ mean? I would love to look into if there is any good material to read and learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> How much current is required for a 64x32  LED matrix?
>
> Spec says 4A max at 5V, when all LEDs (SMD3528 16mA) on
>
> Why not 16mA x 64 x 32 ~= 32A?

***Short Answer***

*How the LED matrix works*

> Well, when they say "all LEDs on", they are a bit misleading. 
>   Actually they are "scanning" the LEDs.  Each LED is only repeatedly on
>   for a short time, cheating the dummy hunman eye and stupid brain that it is
>   on all the time. The brief description might help to explain deeper.

*Case 1 - All LEDs on.*

> 1. LED scanner starts with LED #1, switches it on for a short time, usually less than 1/25 second, before moving on to LED #2.
> 2. Similarly, LED scanner switches on LED # 2 for a short time, then moves to LED #3, #4, #5, and so on, ...
> 3. When LED scanner reaches last LED #2048 (16 * 32 = 2048), it goes back to LED #1 to repeat another cycle.

*Case 2 - Some LEDs on, some off*

> Similar to Case 1, except when the "off" LED's turn comes, scanner
>   switches it off (not on!) for a short time.

*Case 3 - Some LEDs on, some off, some very bright, some not so bright*

> Similar to Case 2, except that when the "not so bright" LED's turn
>   comes, scanner switches the LED say, four times, by 4 pulses, in the the very 
>   short time of 1/25 second.  For each of the 4 switching on/off, the width of 
>   the pulse determines how long is the on time.  Wider pulse means longer time on 
>   and shorter time off, On the other hand, shorter pulse means short time on, 
>   longer time off. This is what the geeks called PWM -Pulse Width Modulation.

[image: PWM]

*Max current calculation*

Spec says scan rate is 1/16, therefore

> max current
>
> = 16 * 32 * 16mA x 1/16
>
> = 2048 * 16mA x 1/16
>
> = 32A / 16
>
> ~= 4A (well, approximately, depending on LED, sometimes much more than
>   16mA)

***References***

[AdaFruit 64x32 RGB LED Matrix - 4mm pitch - US$80](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2278)

[AdaFruit 64x32 RGB LED Matrix Tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix/)

[Lumimicro 3528 Super luminosity SMD White LED (3V4 20mA) Datasheet](http://downloads.cdn.re-in.de/150000-174999/154355-da-01-en-LED_WARM_WEISS_SMD_900_MCD_TYP_120_GRAD.pdf)

[image: led matrix]

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. Now it makes a lot of sense to me!

Comment: You are welcome.  Have a colourful day!

Comment: @cypark I have added a over simplified PWM picture, in case you or other newbies wish to know a little bit more, so the geeks won't LOL at you~ :)

Comment: gorgeous drawing! Thanks, now im one step closer to the geeks ;)